# why the window will not jump or scroll when I apply position:fixed to the body?

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>body{position:fixed}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='height:30px;width:3000px'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After I set position:fixed to the body Element,the window will not scroll.Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.element    { position:fixed; top:2%; right:2%;
```

Above we set our element 2% from both the top and right hand side of the viewport. You can scroll on the page forever but our element will still stick to the specified 2% mark. You can see fixed positioning in effect on the Facebook website (chat toolbar).

OR 
you can refer to

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you seeing this [article](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/css-tips-how-to-use-the-position-fixed-property/).

When you `position: fixed` something it is positioned relative to the browser window and so body doesnot moves or scrolls!

See example it @ [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed)

Comment: But I don't set overflow:hidden ,why the overflow is hidden?

Comment: Because it's position:fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

> `body{position:fixed}` it will apply for whole document. take an element and apply Same thing then you can have scroll. Position fixed will take 100% width of screen fixed so it won't be scroll.